# How can GNU time utility ignores pipe symbol and takes all what left in command line as one execve argument?

Tags: c, linux, time, pipe, gnu

Linux, if I run `time tar -c stock_file | lz4 > stock_file.lz4`, actually it makes something like `time (tar -c stock_file | lz4 > stock_file.lz4)`, but if I write one little program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        printf("The %dth user parameter, %s\n", i, argv[1]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Then I build it to `pretending_time` and run it:

```
shell@kernel: ~> ./pretending_time well | cat
The 1th user parameter, well
```

Well well, the parameter is `well` not `well | cat`, then I have the check the source code of `time` to figure it out how `time` takes `well | cat` as one parameter

```
git clone git://git.savannah.gnu.org/time.git
```

Only one file source code, feels good

```
int
main (argc, argv)
     int argc;
     char **argv;
{
  const char **command_line;
  RESUSE res;

  ......
}
```

Feels not good, compile it carefully

```
error: ‘argc’ was not declared in this scope
error: ‘argv’ was not declared in this scope
error: initializer expression list treated as compound expression
error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘int’
error: expected unqualified-id before ‘{’ token
```

What is

```
int
main (argc, argv)
     int argc;
     char **argv;
{
```

I have never seen it before, and I can't compile it, is this allowed in c-lang? is this the way how `time` takes the pipe symbol `|` in the parameter?

**EDIT after wondering solved**

There is one builtin command `time` in my shell, but `which` will find the standalone `time` utility, you can if there is builtin by

```
shell@kernel: ~> help | grep -Eo "\btime .*"
time [-p] pipeline
```

Comment: `main (argc, argv)
     int argc;
     char **argv;
` is prehistoric syntax and not standard. It is outdated since ca. 27 years now. Use prototype-style declarators and parameter list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `time` behaves differently than other (external) programs is because `time` is not actually a program, it's a bash builtin. For comparison, consider the following examples: with the bash builtin we get

```
$ time sleep 1 | sleep 2
real   0m2.003s
```

whereas with the external time

```
$ /usr/bin/time sleep 1 | sleep 2
0.00user 0.00system 0:01.00elapsed 0%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 7488maxresident)k
```

So as you can see, in first case `time` times both `sleep` operations, whereas in the second case it only times the first `sleep`. In general, it is impossible to build a version of `time` as an external program that works like the first example. The reason is that whenever bash see the pipe character, it will execute the stuff on the left and the stuff on the right independently. So the left side will never have a chance to see what the right side command looks like. On the other hand, with the builtin `time`, bash can recognize it and treat it specially.